# Log4j not writing logs to file on one Websphere server and writing to file on other

Tags: java, log4j, websphere

I have maven application with log4j.properties in it with setting to write the logs to a specified file instead of console. When I run the EAR on one of the websphere servers it is creating the file as expected and writing logs to it. But, when I am running the same EAR on other webspehere server it is writing to console instead of writing the logs to the specified file. I have checked the permissions and everything seems to be fine. Please help me in identifying what the issue is. Thanks in advance.

```
 # CONSOLE APPENDER (stdout)
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] [%t] %-5p %20c - %m%n

# ROLLING FILE APPENDER (on the file system) for memberpolicyattributesservice code
log4j.appender.xxxxService=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.xxxxService.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.xxxxService.File=/var/logs/xxxServer1/xxxServiceLog.log
log4j.appender.xxxxService.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.xxxxService.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM-dd@HH:mm:ss} %-5p (%13F:%L) %3x - %m%n 
log4j.appender.xxxxService.MaxFileSize=10000KB
log4j.appender.xxxxService.MaxBackupIndex=30
log4j.appender.xxxxService.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.xxxxService.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] [%t] %-5p %20c - %m%n



# ROLLING FILE APPENDER (on the file system) for hiberate, open source code log files
log4j.appender.open_source_code=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.open_source_code.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.open_source_code.Threshold=DEBUG
#message format:YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss,ms [ThreadId] <PRIORITY> classname.message
log4j.appender.open_source_code.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t]<%-5p> %c.%m \r\n
#file that will be logged to
log4j.appender.open_source_code.File=/var/logs/xxxServer1/open_source_code.log
log4j.appender.open_source_code.Append=true
log4j.appender.open_source_code.MaxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.open_source_code.MaxBackupIndex=5


#turn on log4j verbose mode
log4j.debug = true

# Set root logger level to INFO and its  appender to DSInstrumentor,stdout.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,stdout,xxxxService


# YOUR CATEGORIES (to customize logging per class/pkg/project/etc)
log4j.category.fatal=FATAL,xxxxService
log4j.category.error=ERROR,xxxxService


#This will also enable the logging for all the children (packages and classes) of this package

log4j.logger.com.xxxxx=ALL,xxxxService

# Print only messages of level INFO  in the open source code
log4j.logger.org=INFO,open_source_code
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple loggers defined in your root logger (DEBUG, stdout, xxxxService) but the xxxxService loggers look like they're bound to the file system on one of the systems:

log4j.appender.open_source_code.File=/var/logs/**xxxServer1**/open_source_code.log

Make sure that path is valid for each server in your WAS cluster.

As a side note, you should probably avoid using debug and stdout on a remote server. This is fine for local development in your workstation, but not on a remote box. Instead, provide different log4j properties on your various deployment tiers. This lets you customize the log location or appender (say c:\temp or CONSOLE on your desktop, but /var/logs ... on all remote machines) as well as your log levels (DEBUG for desktop, maybe INFO for QA or Staging, and WARN or ERROR for Production).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have even tried removing the multiple loggers in my root logger and found that it did not work on the server. Thanks for the suggestion on log level, but I am trying to deploy the application for the first time on that server and hence had the log level as "debug" instead of "info".

Comment: The path is same on both the servers, but the logging is still being written to console on one of the servers, while it is working fine on other. I still do not understand if any server level configuration has to be changed. Please let me know if you are aware of any.